# Is there a substance I can use to coat a projectile to eliminate friction heat?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat

Let's say that I was going to shoot a can of beer into space from one of those "[vacuum cannons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YYNCGZCul1Q)." I would expect that the friction with the air around the projectile would cause the whole thing to just melt and burn (explode).

Is there such a substance that, if used to coat the projectile of my contraption, would eliminate the heat problem by basically "consuming the heat in a reaction" on the way out of the atmosphere?

Comment: Daresay if you had such a coating you'd be a multi-quadrijillionaire.

Comment: Large bodies such as meteors burn while plunging through the atmosphere because of [adiabatic compression of the air in front of them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ram_pressure), rather than friction. I'm not sure whether the same remains true for an object as small as a beer can. I suspect the beer can would actually remain quite cool, as the [square-cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-cube_law) law suggests heat would be transferred proportionally much more efficiently away from the beer can.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto Uh. Jinx...ish?

Comment: @Brian Pretty darn close, though I had to edit some more stuff in!

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto Yours is a lot more substantial, so all in all I'd say you win.

Comment: I guess you're talking about ablative coating, like used for atmospheric reentries - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_entry#Ablative

Comment: A quite common technique is to put a small hole in the top of the beer can such that a thin film of beer could flow around the can cooling it.

Comment: IF something is travelling really fast through the atmosphere, *friction* heat may not be the biggest problem. So eliminating friction won't keep the beer cool.

Answer (score 2):

Try using carbon fiber in a uniquely woven shape. Maybe apply a dual layer with the top layer having a unique shape for heat dissipation. There have been a few carbon fiber helix designs that maintained structure and supported weight with a 2000 F acetylene/butane flame directed on it.

Another option is go with layers of powdered graphite. See if you can convert thermochemical properties with blends. Maybe you can add a coolant system for your beer can with the excess energy stored.

If you are really trying to have your beer survive extreme heat,"Thermo-electric Reactions and Currents Between Metals in Fused Salts" by Thomas Andrews is probably a good start for prototype blends. I think google has a free .pdf available through Google books.

[Here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8e/Steel_pd.svg/2000px-Steel_pd.svg.png) is a graph that might help with selecting your surface metals, if you ever take this project on seriously:

[image]

If nothing works, at least your efforts should land you a pretty hardcore beer-koozie.

Final deciding factors come down to the degree of effort you are wishing to exert and material expense.

Comment: Do you want to break up this post into a few more readable paragraphs? Also, you can insert photos using the image button above the text.